# How to prepare grid view columns array using model or controller in yii2?

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model, yii2-grid

I am using yii2 grid view widget like below

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'visible' => empty($visbleValue) ? '1':'0',
            'value' => function($model){                   
                return $model->name;
            }
        ],         
        [   
            'attribute' => 'account',
            'visible' => empty($visbleValue) ? '0':'1',
            'value' => function($model){                
                return implode(', ', ArrayHelper::map($model->accounts, 'id', 'account_name'));
            }
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'Document',
            'visible' => empty($visbleValue) ? '1':'0',
            'value' => function($model, $index, $column) {
               return Document::findOne(['user_id' => $model->id,])->document_name;
            },
            'label' => 'Document',
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

This all are working fine, but i want prepare columns array values(attribute values like name,account,document) using model or controller, how to do that.

**Controller**

```
public function actionVerficationDetails()
{      
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $visbleValue= $session->get('visbleValue');
    $searchModel = new VerficationDetailsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    return $this->render('VerficationDetails', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'visbleValue' => $visbleValue,
    ]); 
}
```

Here i print dataprovider it will print some empty query objects, no data will come. Please help anyone.

Comment: I hope i can help you,but the problem is about the technical terms in question , will you please make it simple ? What output or how the output you want to be in view page ?

Comment: your question is not clear  .. try explain better your need

Comment: Sorry for in convenience.Simply i want  pass variable in grid view widget column like that **'columns' =>$variable**